# Database design for many(few) to many(actually too many) relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables, user and programs. Now I have only, say, 5-10, programs and tens of thousands of users, who can be enrolled in any of the programs (can be enrolled in multiple programs too). So in a case of many to many relationship, I was thinking of creating a separate table, say link_user_program, to store which programs a user is enrolled in.

But if I have tens of thousands of user and just 10 programs, won't this **consume extra space and increase query time** than just storing the programs enrolled in the user table (maybe comma separated program ids or a boolean column for each program)?

What are the pros and cons of the above two designs or is there a better alternative? What if there's a situation that new programs may be added in the future (but still way considerably less than the number of users)?

Comment: Read an introduction to relational DBMSs & database design. (Which is effectively what your question is asking for as an answer.) The third table is the appropriate design. You clearly have to learn a lot more about straightforward use of RDBMSs before you need to start being concerned about hand optimization.

Answer (score 0):

From OO domain design perspective, recommend to use a many to many link table;
forget about extra space, for query time, you can setup index to improve performance.

without link table, if will make you difficult to add/delete a problem in future.

Comment: [_Details on optimal design of many-to-many table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).